# A fair coin is tossed until at least 1 head and at least 1 tail appears.

Tags: probability

What is the probability that at least 3 coin tosses will be needed?

I am at a loss on how to calculate this probability. I have found that the sample space will be

$S=2^n-2$

For two tosses, 2 out of 4 will follow the condition.
For three tosses, 6 out of 8 will follow the condition.
For four tosses, 14 out of 16 will follow the condition. And so on.
Reading a bit about how to go about the solution. I have found that the expected number of coin flips for at least 1 head and at least 1 tail will be 3 (still kind of unsure as to how this is true). https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-expected-number-of-coin-flips-until-you-get-one-head-and-one-tail

Is this on the right path on how to find the probability?

Comment: There are only two paths to consider.  Expectation has nothing to do with this.

Comment: Should say: the question is not clear. Are you asking "what is the probability that exactly three tosses are needed" or "what is the probability that at least three tosses are needed" ?

Comment: Understood. I myself am not sure. As the question is phrased that way. Both would be interesting to look at though. I have edited the question.

Comment: Either way, just count the relevant paths.

Comment: For P(exactly three tosses needed) I would believe the probability is equal to $(1/2)^3$

Comment: Why? There are two paths that take three tosses.

Answer (score 2):

The condition is equivalent to having either two tails followed by one head, or two heads followed by one tail. By symmetry those two probabilities are equal, so it's just 2 $\times$ the probability of two heads in a row.

Answer (score 2):

Another way to do it: invert the question, and ask what the probability is that you'll do it in the first two flips.

The first flip doesn't matter. The second would need to be the opposite of whatever your first flip was, which'll happen half the time.

So, a $\dfrac{1}{2}$ chance of one heads and one tails in the first two flips. Thus it's also $1-\dfrac{1}{2}=\dfrac{1}{2}$ chance of it taking $3$ or more flips.